# BeeWare Android App development: How can I access and save data on a phone with my app

Tags: android, json, beeware

I am in the process of trying to developp a small app with BeeWare for Android for my own use. The purpose of the app is to pick a random word from a pre-built list, and ask the user for the translation (english to korean, or korean to english), and then check if it is correct or not. The app also should offer the option of curating the list, by adding or updating entries of the dictionnary holding the words.
To this end, I need to store the data somewhere on the device, and to be able to access it. When I run it locally using 'briefcase dev' I can just use the local path to the data but it obviously doesn't work on the since it can't access that same data.
My question is: how do I add data (preferably in .json format) to the project, and how can I then use it to read or update it.

I initially developped this project only for desktop, by using 'input' functions etc. but I would like to be able to have a slightly more complex interface.

When I use the app locally, I can use the direct path to the data, but I don't know which path I should use when the app is packaged.

Answer (score 1):

Your `App` object has a [`paths`](https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/app.html#toga.app.App.paths) attribute, with the following sub-attributes:

- `app`: for read-only access to files from your source code directory
- `data`: for read-write access to any other files you want to create

Comment: not work in android , but work in linux output .

Comment: @alireza: It should work on all platforms. If you had a problem, please create an issue on the [Toga GitHub page](https://github.com/beeware/toga/issues).

Answer (score 0):

the following paths on phone are W/R granted and you can write and read there

"/storage/emulated/0/documents"
"/storage/emulated/0/downloads"
"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM"

Answer (score 0):

For my project (Beeware android) In using the App.paths property I create the file if it does not exist (first run), and the next time my app starts it will see the file and load the data saved before. Only downside is wanting to initially have the file present from the start with data but for me this was not needed.

```
def load_data(self, filename="food_data.json"):
    file_path = self.app.paths.data / filename

    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
        return [FoodItem.from_dict(item) for item in data]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return []

def save_data(self, food_list, filename="food_data.json"):
    data = [food_item.to_dict() for food_item in food_list]
    file_path = self.app.paths.data / filename

    # Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    file_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)
```